# Retrieving custom entity data in Shopware's CMS editor from component

Tags: vue.js, shopware, shopware6

In a Shopware vue component, for the editor/designer in the administration, I got the following code to fetch data from a custom entity:

```js
fetchTeam({ targetId }) {
  this.teamRepository.get(targetId).then((team) => {
    this.$set(this.element.data, 'team', team);
  });
},
```

**This almost works.** E.g. It sends a HTTP request to the API and retrieves the expected data; the problem is that the data is never added to `this.element.data`; The `team` property is added, but it is always filled with `null` as value.

I was trying to find inspiration from Shopware's own code, and they have something very similar to this, but I am not sure if I am using the code in the wrong context.

In developer tools I can see that the XHR request is performed, and it returns the expected data, so presumably this is just a minor issue.

**What I want to do:**
My idea is this:

1. Rather than saving all the data in the CMS element config, I want to have it fetched from the backend when editing a page.
2. When saving the page with the custom *CMS element* on from the editor, an ID for the entity should be saved in the element config, which is used elsewhere (in the editor and storefront) to retrieve data from the entity.
3. Finally, in the storefront I would also re-fetch the data. I have not started this code yet, but hope it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea. Store the ID of the entity in your elements config and then create a [CMS Element Resolver](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-data-to-cms-elements) that fetches the data for your element using that ID.

```php
class MyElementResolver extends AbstractCmsElementResolver
{
    public function getType(): string
    {
        return 'myElementType';
    }

    public function collect(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext): ?CriteriaCollection
    {
        $teamConfig = $slot->getFieldConfig()->get('team');

        if (!$teamConfig) {
            return null;
        }

        $teamId = $teamConfig->getValue();
        $criteria = new Criteria([$teamId]);

        $criteriaCollection = new CriteriaCollection();
        $criteriaCollection->add('team_' . $slot->getUniqueIdentifier(), TeamDefinition::class, $criteria);

        return $criteriaCollection;
    }

    public function enrich(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext, ElementDataCollection $result): void
    {
        $searchResult = $result->get('team_' . $slot->getUniqueIdentifier());
        if (!$searchResult) {
            return;
        }

        $teamConfig = $slot->getFieldConfig()->get('team');

        $team = $searchResult->get($teamConfig->getValue());
        if (!$team instanceof TeamEntity) {
            return;
        }

        $slot->setData($team);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, because I can see that the data is available and returned in developer tools. E.g. The XHR request seem to return the raw JSON string response. Should this not be sufficient? When I `console.log` it from my vue component I get a `promise {pending}` (even inside `.then()`). I am still fairly new to vue, but should it not be possible to simply `.json()` it? PHP seems a bit overkill'ish just to get some data.

Comment: Well, I mean... it's a PHP based framework  You're referencing your custom entity in the element. An entities data is, due to the nature of entities, subject to change at any time. When you create your element and essentially create a snapshot of the data at the current time, you're losing the benefits of entity references. That's why you normally would want to store away only the id for reference and then fetch the entity in its current state, each time the element is resolved. Also keep in mind, that response you're getting is only requested in the admin, when you edit the element.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. But I am still confused because this part I am having problems with is in vue, and seem to be a vue/JS problem rather than a PHP one. I send the request from the editor, that is, the component part of my cms-element, on creation. E.g. Inside the `created() {}` hook. This is only to retrieve the data when the editor first opens, via the ID that a user selected previously in the config part. I am just wondering why I can't seem to use/obtain the JSON response it actually *does* return as a result of calling `this.teamRepository.get(targetId)`.

Comment: Did you also emit the update of the element? `this.$emit('element-update', this.element);` I suggest you take a look at [this component](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/elements/buy-box/config/index.js#L60) for reference. It stores the product data, only for the preview of the element in the administration, and the product id to be resolved in the storefront.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out I was probably missing a `Criteria`. E.g. `const { Criteria } = Shopware.Data;` at the top of my component. I needed this when doing a `customRepository.get()`. Some examples I was looking at was missing this, so no wonder it caused confusion. It is working now. I even added the `Resolver` you recommended.